# Task Scheduler Launch Failure error value 2147943726

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to schedule a task on Windows Server 2012.

I have seen in different forums that the issue is with an expired password, but I am doing this with a `gMSA`..

Here is the script:

```
# Create a trigger (Everyday at 3pm)

$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 15:00

#Create task action

$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute cmd.exe -Argument "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\Users\####.bat"

#Settings Configuration

$Settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable -Compatibility Win8

#Set service account and privileges

$principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId 'domain.local\serviceaccount$' -LogonType Password -RunLevel Highest

#Schedule Task

Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "test_task_MSA" -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -Settings $Settings -Principal $principal
```

This is the error I get:

```
Task Scheduler failed to start "\test_task_MSA" task for user "domain.local\serviceaccount$". Additional Data: Error Value: 2147943726.
```

Changed compatibility to Win8 and added the service account to log on as batch local policy security settings.

Comment: You're mixing up cmd and powershell parameters.

Comment: i am guessing you are refeering to the -noprofile -executionpolicy parameters? i have removed them but still the same error

Comment: There's no -file option either.  You would just run the .bat file directly.

Comment: So i should only include -argument and then the file path?

Comment: What @js2010 is saying is that you should use `$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute C:\Users\####.bat`

Comment: Thanks @mklement0. Unfortunately the task still fails to start with the same error value :(

Comment: If this works when you manually create the Task, I would create a task manually, create a task via the powershell commands, then export both and compare and check the differences in the XML files.

Comment: Thanks @KG-DROID. I cannot create a task via the GUI with a managed service account. Only through the PowerShell.. Which leads me to believe the error is in that account itself... I just checked the AD attributes of the MSA and for whatever reason the bad password set is going up by one every time i try to run the task.. How can a service account have a bad password when its managed by the domain controller? very very strange

Comment: Have you setup this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/group-managed-service-accounts/create-the-key-distribution-services-kds-root-key

Comment: @KG-DROID yes i have - i also did a test-ADServiceAccount to ensure the account was installed on the required computers and it returns a TRUE value

Comment: What privileges have you given to the service account?

Comment: On the PowerShell Task Scheduler script the run level is highest. i also added the service account to the administrators group in AD